# Loading function arguments on a stack and then running the function in C

Tags: c, function, stack, arguments

I wanted to know if there is a way to load function arguments on a stack and then run the function so that it can pop those arguments and use them as input.

Suppose I have a function `void f1(int a, int b , int c)` and I want to pass it values (1,2,3) .... can I load these values onto the stack and then call the function f1 so that it would take these values in order and run. (basically I want to know a way to pass these values to the function without using the function definition).

Comment: Why would you don't wanna use function arguments, and force you to create some extra struct or array to have it?

Comment: C does not mandate a stack. Calling conventions differ between implementations and may not require passing arguments on a stack either, at least for a small number of arguments. Bottom line: You can do this kind of thing in assembly, but not in conforming C.

Comment: That's basically how the stdcall calling convention works. Since C doesn't support native pushing and popping of the stack, you'd need to use assembly here.

Comment: The project that I am working on gives me function pointer which points to a function that I don't know about and it gives me a list which contains the arguments to the functions (user is supposed to give the function pointer input and the arguments).... since different function can have different number of input arguments I want to know if there is a general way to run those functions ( like using a stack )

Comment: Don't down vote the question for no reason :\

Answer (score -1):

Not knowing your intent, perhaps you can use [va_args](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson17.html). This is the mechanism used to pass variable number of arguments to e.g. printf()

Comment: The project that I am working on gives me function pointer which points to a function ( that has definite number of arguments ) that I don't know about and it gives me a list which contains the arguments to the functions (user is supposed to give the function pointer input and the arguments).... since different function can have different number of input arguments I want to know if there is a general way to run those functions ( like using a stack )

Comment: Why not simply pass a structure containing all the arguments, then casting it to void*, then the called routines cast their only void* argument to whatever they needs ?